# Why is Google Datastore responding with (400) Bad Request?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore

I am using [node-simplecrawler](https://github.com/cgiffard/node-simplecrawler) to crawl the web. It saves the crawled links every few seconds to Google Cloud Datastore but after the first 10-20 saved links, Google Datastore starts to respond with `Bad Request`.

Comment: Does the error contain any additional information? What client are you using to write to Cloud Datastore?

Comment: @EdDavisson I use the official gcloud library for node.js. It just responds with a Bad Request, I thought it's too much because my crawler uploaded approx. one link every second, so I used a timeout but that did not help.

Comment: It sounds like a bug in the gcloud-node library that you're not getting a more specific error message. I'm following up in https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-node/issues/1378 if you want to follow along.